# ext4 - Remove ability to encrypt disk even for root

Tags: 22.04, encryption, disk, ext4

I was wondering if this is possible: remove the ability to encrypt a disk/partition?

It occured to me that it's a possible attack vector to encrypt the disk with a key if you manage to get root access.

What if that functionality just... wasn't there?

I seem to recall certain filesystems have the functionality deprecated or not there? Am I imagining things?

Is it possible to disable this?

Comment: If an attacker has access to your computer so she can turn on encryption she could also do all kinds of bad things .. including deleting your data and/or filesystems or physically remove your disks, So the only way to keep  your system safe is to keep attackers out and away from the hardware.

Comment: You can't just magically convert an existing filesystem to an encrypted one (yet), so this functionality is already there

Answer (score 0):

Root, by definition, can do anything that the software is capable of doing.
Root, by definition, cannot be limited in software.

Encryption is less important than the compromise. The compromise exposes you to ongoing penetration by newly-planted backdoors and poisoned files and other tricks. If an attacker encrypts or steals your files, you don't want those (poisoned) files back. Better to wipe, reinstall, and restore from backups.

But since you specifically asked about encryption...

The packages that provide encryption capability are not secret, and it is trivial for an attacker --human or malware-- to check for the presence of those packages.

Since your scenario assumes that the attacker has root access, it would also be trivial for them to install or re-install those packages...or to do all kinds of other terrible things.

If you are worried about security, your first mitigation is regular backups.

English-speakers who want to learn about security can get a great overview from a few episodes of the [Ubuntu Security Podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/).